Emacs calc: Apply function to vector
In calc, I have the following:
1. [1, 2, 3]
2. x + 1

I want to apply the function in 2 to every value of the vector as it's argument, so the result should look like this:
1. [2, 3, 4]

Is there a way to do this? I tried with the mapping functionalities V M +, V M -, etc and they are close to what I need, but not quite.
I know that V M ' exists, and it's pretty close, but I'd like to use an equation that's on the stack.

I think I found the answer.
Having in the stack:
1. [1, 2, 3]
2. x + 1

If you press V M $, it will prompt for an argument list, being (x) the default. It will then apply the function to all the elements in the vector.
Note: The order is important, first the vector, then the function.
For more information visit: the documentation.

That is indeed the relevant piece. It says: If you press $ at the operator prompt, the effect is similar to the apostrophe except that the relevant formula is taken from top-of-stack instead. The actual vector arguments of the V A $ or related command then start at the second-to-top stack position. You will still be prompted for an argument list. 

Oh, I see. I was trying V M ' $. By prompt I understood V M ''s prompt. Thanks Nick! I'll edit the question accordingly.
